# How to define dynamic has_many relationship depending on if another model/table exists in Rails 3.2.12?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, has-many

There are `customers` and `projects` model in our Rails app. However `project` model may or may not present along with the `customer` model. Their relationship are:

```
class Project
  belongs_to :customer, :class_name => 'Customer'
end

class Customer
  has_many :projects, :class_name => 'Project', :conditions => if projects model exists
end
```

Basically we would like to make the has_many in customer model dynamic depending on if the project model exists. Is this something doable in Rails 3.2.12?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow. If you need to have a dynamic association based on if the associated class is defined, then you'd write something along these lines:

```
class Customer
   if defined? Project
      has_many :projects, :class_name => 'Project'
   end
end
```

If you meant a model like an object or record in database, then I'm not sure why the association can't stay where it is.

### Update

Yes you can do that in one line. But take caution, that this woun't work as expected in development environment, since config.cache_classes is set to false, the 'defined? Project' will always return nil unless you explicitly call it.

If you need to test this behaviour then set config.cache_classes = true in your development.rb ( note that this will ignore code changes unless you restart your server ).

```
class Customer
   has_many :projects, :class_name => 'Project' if defined? Project
end
```

Comment: yes, we need to have a dynamic association based on if the associated class is defined. Can we put this into one line like: has_many :projects, :class_name => 'Project if defined? Project     thanks.